# Учебник русского языка или учебник по русскому языку?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, правильный вариант употребления. Слышала оба, но "учебник русского языка" немного режет слух почему-то.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно именно "учебник русского языка" (хотя пособие, тесты, контрольные работы "по русскому языку"). Сложилось так, что слово "учебник" трансформирует глагольное управление (учить чему) на существительное (учебник чего). Чтобы убедиться в таком положении дел, достаточно поискать гуглом изображения обложек "учебников" с такими надписями - они найдутся только в варианте "... русского языка".

Answer (score 2):

-Вопрос (на Грамоте. ру) : https://otvet.mail.ru/question/79511730

-Добрый день! Подскажите, как правильно говорить и писать. Учебник по русскому языку или учебник русского языка? Спасибо! Under-713

- Ответ справочной службы русского языка:

Оба варианта верны.

учебник русского языка - Род. пад. , учебник по русскому языку - Дат. пад.

Вот прямая ссылка на Грамоту: http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=257260